# Does modifying the RetryOptions passed to CallActivityWithRetry Async require versioning orchestration function?

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I've always been hesitant when making changes to orchestrator code because understanding the specifics of what is breaking vs a non breaking change has never been 100% clear to me despite reading the documentation over and over. I worry that I will break in-flight orchestrations and typically error on the side of caution.

In this case I really would prefer not to have to version, but I'm not sure of this qualifies as a change. I am currently calling CallActitivityWithRetryAsync in my orchestration and would like to set a value of 2.0 to BackoffCoefficient.

My question is whether or not setting this value would would break in-flight orchestrations and requires versioning my orchestration function so the two can work side by side.

Current:

```
var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 5);
await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("MyActivity", retryOptions, null);
```

Desired:

```
var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 5) 
retryOptions.BackoffCoefficient = 2.0;
await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("MyActivity", retryOptions, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran this by Chris Gillum from the Durable Functions team and the answer is: it depends.

> Changing the retry options settings could change the history that gets generated by your orchestrator function. For example, if making a retry policy change results in more or fewer retries for existing instances, they may fail with a non-determinism error.

In the case of the specific example asked by the OP a version change should *not* be required as it is simply changing the backoff coefficient and would not result in any changes to max attempts.